# URL redirect using htaccess file, url friendly to url friendly redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have a url that I want to redirect

OLD URL -> https://www.my-webiste.com/products/title-of-product

NEW URL ->https://www.my-website.com/title-of-product

On google we have everywhere old url and we changed the site with new layout and CMS so we redirected our domains ( old-website.com -> new-website.com this works well ) but I am not sure how I can able to pass this parameter to new store, any help?

If that is not possible,then can we load content of https://www.new-website.com/title-of-product on https://www.new-website.com/products/title-of-product url ?

So when user come to my site with old url, in backend system ( htaccess ) will manage to skip "products" keyword internally and show appropriate page.

RewriteRule ^/?products/([^/d]+)/?$ /$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^products/?$ $1/new-page$2 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^products/(\d+)?$ /$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?*route*=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/products/(.*)$ $1/$2 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^products/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^products/(.*)$ /%1 [L,R=301]

I tried all of these but I am getting 404 with all of above. Rewrite Engine is on as when https://www.new-website.com/title-of-product I open this url it works fine.

In short conclusion is:

i just have to get rid of "products" from the urls and send that parameters.

if someone open https://www.my-webiste.com/products/title-of-product then they must be go to https://www.my-webiste.com/title-of-product ( see without products ) That's it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried, or at least what your research has turned up so far.

Comment: RewriteRule ^(.*)/products/(.*)$ $1/$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^products/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^products/(.*)$ /%1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/?products/([^/d]+)/?$ /$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^products/?$ $1/new-page$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^products/(\d+)?$ /$1 [L]

I tried all of these but still not works...

Comment: Please don’t post such longer code snippets in comments, that is hardly readable  - edit your question instead, and format them properly in there. And you also need to explain what “not working” actually means. Do you get a simple 404, or some other kind of error, …?

Comment: Also, what is your setup, do you have both of those domains routed into the same directory? If you want to rewrite from the old domain to the new one, then you can’t use a relative path for the substitution, you’d need an absolute URL that includes the “new” domain.

Comment: Please check post, I updated it.

Comment: Do you have both domains routed into the same directory, are they using the same .htaccess - or is it different ones?

Comment: Both domains are different one... I changed DNS of my hosting to point new domain...

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, please make sure you have rewrite module turned on, can be checked with phpinfo(); function

if it is on, then this code placed in .htaccess file in the main public folder of your project should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^products/(.*)$ https://www.new-website.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: When I tried this code it still goes to 404

The page you requested cannot be found!

Comment: Main question is: are you being redirected to new-website.com or are you seeing 404 on the old-website.com domain? Is the rewrite mod working on the old server/domain - were you able to verify this?

Comment: How about you try something like RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [R=301,L] (place it right after RewriteEngine on)? If mod rewrite works as expected then any request to your old domain should result in redirect loop. If this doesn't occur then you should focus on getting rewrite module working first.

Comment: I changed my CMS domain will be same but url structure on CMS are different so, I need to adopt new url and redirect all urls to appropriate URL

so, domain will be same, I just want to remove "Products" from the url

For example https://www.my-webiste.com/products/title-of-product must redirect to https://www.my-webiste.com/title-of-product

Comment: Then your rule needs to be RewriteRule ^products/(.*)$ $1 [R=301,L], but you still need to first make sure your mod rewrite /.htaccess file work.